# Is there a performant way to "deep merge" two arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of objects: **publications** and **documentPrices**
This is how they look:

```
const publications = [
  {
    id: "publication1",
    documents: [
      {
        id: "document1",
        priceId: "abc",
      },
      {
        id: "document2",
        priceId: "xyz",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "publication2",
    documents: [
      {
        id: "document3",
        priceId: "abc",
      },
      {
        id: "document4",
        priceId: "xyz",
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

```
const documentPrices = [
  { priceId: "abc", priceUsd: 100, priceEur: 120 },
  { priceId: "xyz", priceUsd: 10, priceEur: 12 },
]
```

I want to achieve the following output

```
const publicationsFinal = [
  {
    id: "publication1",
    documents: [
      {
        id: "document 1",
        priceId: "abc",
        priceUsd: 100,
        priceEur: 120,
      },
      {
        id: "document 2", 
        priceId: "xyz",
        priceUsd: 10,
        priceEur: 12,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "publication2",
    documents: [
      {
        id: "document 3",
        priceId: "abc",
        priceUsd: 100,
        priceEur: 120,
      },
      {
        id: "document 4",
        priceId: "xyz",
        priceUsd: 10,
        priceEur: 12,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

At the moment, I have implemented this with 3 nested loops, which is highly inefficient. Also, I have checked other solutions on SO but haven't found one that is relevant to the issue I am facing. Is there an efficient way to achieve the desired output?

Comment: What's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: if each priceid within documentPrices is unique, you could eliminate one of the loop based lookups with a direct one. If they aren't, then you'll need to specify what should occur when there's two.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to *modify* the objects in the `publications` array or create a new array with new objects. But unless you're seeing a performance problem, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Either way, you're going to have two nested loops (publications and documents), there's no getting around it. But you can avoid a third *nested* loop by building a `Map` of the price information up-front:

```
const priceMap = new Map(documentPrices.map((entry) => [entry.priceId, entry]));
```

Looking up the entries in the map is [required by the JavaScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map-objects) to be faster, in general, than looking up the entries in the array would have been. That is: sublinear.

Once you have the map, if you just want to update the existing objects, you have your nested loops:

```
for (const { documents } of publications) {
    for (const doc of documents) {
        const entry = priceMap.get(doc.priceId);
        if (entry) {
            doc.priceEur = entry.priceEur;
            doc.priceUsd = entry.priceUsd;
        }
    }
}
```

(I've used `for-of` loops there. These days, JavaScript engines are very nearly as fast at `for-of` as they are at `for` [when using standard arrays], but if you like you could use just a `for` loop instead.)

Live example:

```js
const publications = [
    {
        id: "publication1",
        documents: [
            {
                id: "document1",
                priceId: "abc",
            },
            {
                id: "document2",
                priceId: "xyz",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "publication2",
        documents: [
            {
                id: "document3",
                priceId: "abc",
            },
            {
                id: "document4",
                priceId: "xyz",
            },
        ],
    },
];
const documentPrices = [
    { priceId: "abc", priceUsd: 100, priceEur: 120 },
    { priceId: "xyz", priceUsd: 10, priceEur: 12 },
];

const priceMap = new Map(documentPrices.map((entry) => [entry.priceId, entry]));

for (const { documents } of publications) {
    for (const doc of documents) {
        const entry = priceMap.get(doc.priceId);
        if (entry) {
            doc.priceEur = entry.priceEur;
            doc.priceUsd = entry.priceUsd;
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(publications, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you want a new array with new objects, you'd have nested `map` calls (which are loops):

```
const result = publications.map((publication) => {
    publication = {
        ...publication,
        documents: publication.documents.map((doc) => {
            const entry = priceMap.get(doc.priceId);
            if (entry) {
                doc = {
                    ...doc,
                    priceEur: entry.priceEur,
                    priceUsd: entry.priceUsd,
                };
            }
            return doc;
        }),
    };
    return publication;
});
```

Live example:

```js
const publications = [
    {
        id: "publication1",
        documents: [
            {
                id: "document1",
                priceId: "abc",
            },
            {
                id: "document2",
                priceId: "xyz",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "publication2",
        documents: [
            {
                id: "document3",
                priceId: "abc",
            },
            {
                id: "document4",
                priceId: "xyz",
            },
        ],
    },
];
const documentPrices = [
    { priceId: "abc", priceUsd: 100, priceEur: 120 },
    { priceId: "xyz", priceUsd: 10, priceEur: 12 },
];

const priceMap = new Map(documentPrices.map((entry) => [entry.priceId, entry]));

const result = publications.map((publication) => {
    publication = {
        ...publication,
        documents: publication.documents.map((doc) => {
            const entry = priceMap.get(doc.priceId);
            if (entry) {
                doc = {
                    ...doc,
                    priceEur: entry.priceEur,
                    priceUsd: entry.priceUsd,
                };
            }
            return doc;
        }),
    };
    return publication;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you don't mind creating a new object even if the price information isn't found, it can be a bit more concise:

```
const result = publications.map((publication) => ({
    ...publication,
    documents: publication.documents.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc,
        // `get` returns `undefined` if not found, which is safe to use with property spread
        ...priceMap.get(doc.priceId),
    })),
}));
```

Live example:

```js
const publications = [
    {
        id: "publication1",
        documents: [
            {
                id: "document1",
                priceId: "abc",
            },
            {
                id: "document2",
                priceId: "xyz",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "publication2",
        documents: [
            {
                id: "document3",
                priceId: "abc",
            },
            {
                id: "document4",
                priceId: "xyz",
            },
        ],
    },
];
const documentPrices = [
    { priceId: "abc", priceUsd: 100, priceEur: 120 },
    { priceId: "xyz", priceUsd: 10, priceEur: 12 },
];

const priceMap = new Map(documentPrices.map((entry) => [entry.priceId, entry]));

const result = publications.map((publication) => ({
    ...publication,
    documents: publication.documents.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc,
        // `get` returns `undefined` if not found, which is safe to use with property spread
        ...priceMap.get(doc.priceId),
    })),
}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn `documentPrices` into a map:

```
const documentPrices = [...]

const documentPricesMap = documentPrices.reduce((acc,p) => {
    acc[p.priceId] = p
    return acc
},{})
```

and then merge:

```
publications.forEach(p => {
    p.documents.forEach((d) => Object.assign(d,documentPricesMap[d.priceId]))
})
```

The above mutates, you can also do it by not mutating:

```
const newPublications = publications.map(p => ({
      ...p,
      documents: p.documents.map(d => ({
        ...d,
        ...documentPricesMap[d.priceId]
      }))
   }
}))
```

Answer (score -1):

There always will be 3 loops. It can't be done without them, but I wouldn't think about performance if you have less than a million records.

In-place version:

```js
const publications = [{
    id: "publication1",
    documents: [{
        id: "document1",
        priceId: "abc",
      },
      {
        id: "document2",
        priceId: "xyz",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "publication2",
    documents: [{
        id: "document3",
        priceId: "abc",
      },
      {
        id: "document4",
        priceId: "xyz",
      },
    ],
  },
]


const documentPrices = [{
    priceId: "abc",
    priceUsd: 100,
    priceEur: 120
  },
  {
    priceId: "xyz",
    priceUsd: 10,
    priceEur: 12
  },
]

for (const pub of publications) {
  for (const doc of pub.documents) {
    const { priceUsd, priceEur } = documentPrices.find(p => p.priceId === doc.priceId)
    doc.priceUsd = priceUsd
    doc.priceEur = priceEur
  }
}


console.log(publications)
```

Creating a new object:

```js
const publications = [{
    id: "publication1",
    documents: [{
        id: "document1",
        priceId: "abc",
      },
      {
        id: "document2",
        priceId: "xyz",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "publication2",
    documents: [{
        id: "document3",
        priceId: "abc",
      },
      {
        id: "document4",
        priceId: "xyz",
      },
    ],
  },
]


const documentPrices = [{
    priceId: "abc",
    priceUsd: 100,
    priceEur: 120
  },
  {
    priceId: "xyz",
    priceUsd: 10,
    priceEur: 12
  },
]

const result = publications.map(pub => ({
  ...pub,
  documents: pub.documents.map(doc => ({
    ...doc,
    ...documentPrices.find(p => p.priceId === doc.priceId)
  }))
}))

console.log(result)
```